# EF return identical Rows for joined tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Created a view Which involve more than four table
When i see the view in Sql it show absolutely ok result
but when i fetch using Entity Framework in Asp.Net MVc

It shows two identical rows although these two rows have different 
values in two columns(qty,amount) and rest column have same value.

Identical row means when i iterate through using foreach loop
it shows that both rows have same result event the qty and amount column
it shows first row result for both the rows

Comment: I have Sorted it out myself the view need a column which should represent unique value.

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior as well.  Guess my fear is true, the view needs a unique key.